# JTable only show 4 rows of data

Tags: java, jtable

I have a sqlite databse and i add data from a arraylist with a lot of data, but the table only show 4 rows, i try to set the table with jswing properties but a dont have good luck.
only show this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbfVK.png]

And the table show this white area. I think is the limit area for rows

and show this area:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWW5p.png]

I want to the table show all data from the list, i mean indefinded rows.

Estaré agradecido si me ayudan con este problema.

Sorry for my english.

Code:

```
public void llenarTabla()
{
    System.out.println("Inicio de llenado de tabla..");
    //registrosTbl.removeAll();
    DefaultTableModel model;

    model = (DefaultTableModel) registrosTbl.getModel();
    int filas= model.getRowCount();
    if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Vaciado de tabla...");
        for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
        {
            model.removeRow(i);
            System.out.println("Eliminada fila: "+i);
        }
        System.out.println("Fin vaciado de tabla...");
    }
    List<Registro> lista = new ArrayList<Registro>();
    lista = FuncionesDB.mostrarTodo();

    if(lista.isEmpty())
    {            
        jScrollPane1.setVisible(false);
        registrosTbl.setVisible(false);

        JLabel mensaje = new JLabel();
        mensaje.setText("No se han realizado consultas");
        mensaje.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        mensaje.setBounds(250, 180, 330, 40);
        mensaje.setVisible(true);

        RegPnl.add(mensaje);


    }else{
        Object rowData[] = new Object[13];
        System.out.println("Llenando tabla...");
        for(int i =0; i< lista.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("numero "+i);

            rowData[0]= lista.get(i).getId();
            rowData[1]= lista.get(i).getNombreNeg();
            rowData[2]= lista.get(i).getEdad();
            rowData[3]= lista.get(i).getCostoProd();
            rowData[4]= lista.get(i).getSueldo();
            rowData[5]= lista.get(i).getUtilidades();
            rowData[6]= lista.get(i).getFormaPago();
            rowData[7]= lista.get(i).getNegocio();
            rowData[8]= lista.get(i).getSexo();
            rowData[9]= lista.get(i).getCompatibilidad();
            rowData[10]= lista.get(i).getRelacionPS();
            rowData[11]= lista.get(i).getResumen();
            rowData[12]= lista.get(i).getFecha();
            model.addRow(rowData);
        }
    }
            System.out.println("Fin llenado..");
}
```

Comment: First of all to delete all the rows from the DefaultTableModel, you can just use `model.setRowCount(0)`. You get your data using `lista = FuncionesDB.mostrarTodo();` so you need to debug your code to determine why it only contains 4 or 2 rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

create a new (Default-)TableModel which is declared to have 4 rows only:

```
public class TableModelWith4rowsOnly{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableModel completeDataFromDatabase = getQeryResultFromDatanaseAsTableModel();
        DefaultTableModel tableModelWith4rowsOnly = new DefaultTableModel(4, completeDataFromDatabase.getColumnCount()) {

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                return completeDataFromDatabase.getValueAt(row, column);
            }

        };
        JTable jTable = new JTable(tableModelWith4rowsOnly);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jTable);
    }

    private static TableModel getQeryResultFromDatanaseAsTableModel() {
        TableModel completeDataFromDatabase = new DefaultTableModel(10, 3) {
            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
                return "value" + new Random().nextInt(4);
            }
        };
        return completeDataFromDatabase;
    }
}
```